# ember: how to convert anchor tag with href to link-to?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

In our ember application, am having some strange requirement.

From the api, am receiving the message which has link to some other page in the same application.

For ex: "offers/1/checkout"

The message am receiving is:

```
"Thanks for the reply. <a href='offers/1/checkout'>Click here</a> to proceed further"
```

Now when we use above message, display it in template, and when User click on the **Click Here** link, the whole app reloads.

Is there any way to stop that reload of app? or can we convert simple **href** to link using **link-to** helper?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to @ember-sherpa.
From the reference he has given above https://github.com/intercom/ember-href-to/blob/master/addon/helpers/href-to.js#L14-L37

I have added a component as follows `app/components/href-to-link.js`

```
// Manually added anchor tags causes whole app to reload.
// This component will treat anchor tag as link-to links.
// Ex: <a href="/offers/1/plan_delivery"></a> will be trated as route "offers.plan_delivery"

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  _getNormalisedRootUrl: function(router) {
    var rootURL = router.rootURL;
    if(rootURL.charAt(rootURL.length - 1) !== '/') {
      rootURL = rootURL + '/';
    }
    return rootURL;
  },

  didInsertElement() {
    var _this = this;
    var router = this.container.lookup("router:main");

    Ember.$().ready(function (){
      Ember.$(".received_message, .my_message").on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        var $target = Ember.$(e.currentTarget);
        var handleClick = (e.which === 1 && !e.ctrlKey && !e.metaKey);

        if(handleClick && !$target.hasClass('ember-view') && Ember.isNone($target.attr('data-ember-action'))) {

          var rootURL = _this._getNormalisedRootUrl(router);
          var url = $target.attr('href');

          if(url && url.indexOf(rootURL) === 0) {
            url = url.substr(rootURL.length - 1);

            if(router.router.recognizer.recognize(url)) {
              router.handleURL(url);
              router.router.updateURL(url);
              return false;
            }
          }
        }
        return true;
      });
    });
  }

});
```

Using it as:

```
{{#href-to-link}}
  ...
{{/href-to-link}}
```

This works perfectly fine!!
Hope this will help others too :)